# Bash kernel in Jupyter Notebook stopped working after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: bash, macos, jupyter-notebook, kernel, macos-catalina

I was using the Bash kernel emulator in Jupyter Notebook while running macOS Mojave, but when I upgraded to Catalina, the kernel emulator stopped working. When I open up an existing Bash notebook or try to open a new one, I get a `Kernel error` message in the upper right of my notebook like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58339508/3266847)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Benjamin W. The issue is not with Python. Python works fine. The issue is with Bash. Jupyter Notebook can run Bash shell commands in the notebook if you run it with a Bash kernel, but that's what's broken.